# Render as GeoJSON (or selectively as WKT/WKB) using MIME-Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geojson, wkt

I have Rails with `PostGIS`, `activerecord-postgis-adapter` and `rgeo-geojson` running.

At the moment I can use default "object.json" URLs to get a JSON string with WKT/WKB format. It looks like this:

```
{"description":null,"id":1,"position":"POINT (10.0 47.0)"}
```

But now I want to have a custom MIME-Type, so I can call "object.geojson" to get GeoJSON format like this:

```
{"description":null,"id":1,"position":{"type":"Point","coordinates": [10.0, 47.0]}}
```

The only way I found to set the JSON-encoder to GeoJSON was to set it globally using `RGeo::ActiveRecord::GeometryMixin.set_json_generator(:geojson)` and `RGeo::ActiveRecord::GeometryMixin.set_json_generator(:wkt)`. **But I just want to set it locally, is this possible?**

I already added `Mime::Type.register "application/json", :geojson, %w( text/x-json application/jsonrequest )` to `mime_types.rb` and it works fine: I can use this code in my controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @object }
  format.geojson { render text: "test" }
end
```

I hope someone can tell me how to render some specific object to GeoJSON without setting the global JSON renderer to `:geojson`. !?

**EDIT:**

My objects look like this in Rails Console:

`#<Anchor id: 1, description: nil, position: #<RGeo::Geos::CAPIPointImpl:0x3fc93970aac0 "POINT (10.0 47.0)">>`

Comment: GeoJSON is JSON and its proper media type is "application/json." Perhaps consider a completely different view for the GeoJSON data?

Comment: Thanks for your answer: But there's still the question: How can I generate JSON with GeoJSON instead of WKT without(!!) setting the global json_generator?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a factory like this for a specific `@object`

```
factory = RGeo::GeoJSON::EntityFactory.instance

feature = factory.feature(@object.position, nil, { desc: @object.description})
```

And encode it:

```
RGeo::GeoJSON.encode feature
```

It should output something like this:

```
{
  "type" => "Feature",
  "geometry" => {
    "type" => "Point",
    "coordinates"=>[1.0, 1.0]
  },
  "properties" => {
    "description" => "something"
  }
}
```

Or a collection of features:

```
RGeo::GeoJSON.encode factory.feature_collection(features)
```

Giving:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      # the rest of the feature...
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      # another feature...
    }
}
```